# ASP.NET Core Web API -How to resolve Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I am implementing async programming in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

I have this code:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Score>> GetExamScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var examScores = _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel == false)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
    return examScores;
}
```

I got this warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work

When I added await before _dbContext.Scores, I got this error:

> Error CS1061  'IOrderedQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IOrderedQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I get this sorted out and apply async  here?

Thank you.

Comment: `public IQueryable<Score> GetExamScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)`

Comment: Your method doesn't contain any `await`s or anything `await`able, so there's no reason to have it marked as `async` or return a `Task`.

Comment: Be aware that your `Where` statements can't be translated to SQL query and will be executed in memory. It means you are going to load all `Scores` rows from DB and then filter out entities that don't match your filter.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling an asynchronous method that returns a `Task`/`Task<T>` so there's nothing to await (and not the right type to return).  Update your method to what Artur suggested in their comment or make another call to generated the `Task` you're looking for (but you wouldn't need `async` and the result type wouldn't be `IQueryable<T>`.  Some simplified possibilities:

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> Get(...)
{
    return dbContext.MyEntities
        .Where(...);
}

public IAsyncEnumerable<MyEntity> Get(...)
{
    return dbContext.MyEntities
        .Where(...)
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();
}

public Task<MyEntity[]> Get(...)
{
    return dbContext.MyEntities
        .Where(...)
        .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

You would use `async` and `await` if you want to use the result of an asynchronous operation later in the same method:

```
public async Task<int> GetCount(...)
{
    var entities = await dbContext.MyEntities
        .Where(...)
        .ToArrayAsync();

    // obviously not efficient but to demonstrate
    // how async/await is used
    return entities.Length;
}
```